# LAN and Bluetooth networks together at the same time

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, lan, bluetooth

I have a wired LAN network for my office and I share my tablet's internet with my windows by Bluetooth. While I don't disable LAN network, I can't connect to the internet with Bluetooth network. When I disable LAN then I can connect to the internet.

My OS is Windows 7, 64 bit.

I want to connect to two networks together at the same time.

Comment: You can't connect to the Bluetooth Internet, or the Internet doesn't work despite being connected to it?

Comment: No, when I disable the LAN connection, my Bluetooth internet work fine but I want to work with both of them concurrently.

Comment: I understand. My question is if you can "connect" (without using the connection to the internet) to the Bluetooth network at the same time you are connected to the LAN? (I think of a possible solution, just wanna verify this 1st.)

Comment: Uh, I'm sorry, I didn't understand your mean exactly. I connect to the Bluetooth internet but the Internet doesn't work. When I disable LAN connection, the Bluetooth internet will work. I hope understand your mean certainly.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that this is an effect of the Network Priority order, in which the wired ethernet LAN has preference over other connections, so the internet traffic tries to go through that network which obviously isn't connected to the internet.

Try to **change the network connection priority**

1. Click **Start** and, in the search field, type **View network connections**, and click on **View network connections** in the results.
2. Press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, click **Advanced** on the menu and then click **Advanced Settings**:
   [image]
3. Select **Local Area Connection** and click the **green down arrow** to move the LAN connection down in the list (to the bottom probably).
   [image]
4. After organizing the network connections available according to your preferences, click **OK**.
5. The computer should now follow the order of priority you configured when detecting available connections. Test if the bluetooth internet works now.

**Source:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2526067

Comment: thanks Yisroel, I changed the priority ( the first is Remote Access Connection and the second is Local Area Connection) but the problem didn't solve.

Comment: You had only these two adapters (local area network and remote access) in the list?

Comment: Yes, only these adapters.

Comment: You may want to try a different method of changing the priority, outlined [here](https://www.google.com/amp/www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/amp/)